# Hook for REST validation with sailsjs

Tags: sails.js

I need to create a validation layer for my REST services, I'm using sailsjs.

Someone know how can I do that?

I tried to create a hook but I cant access routes definitions and the hook is called before start policies :'(

The way is something like picture below.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is perfectly fine to use policies to pre-process requests before they are passed to the controllers. Policies are not just for authentication and acl. They are so versatile you can use them for anything.

E.g.

**policies/beforeUpdateTicket.js**

```
module.exports = function(req, res, ok) {
    TicketService.checkTicket(req.params.id, null, true).then(function(ticket) {
        # You can even modify req.body
        req.body.checked = true;
        return ok();
    }).fail(function(err) {
        # Don't go to the controller, respond with error
        return res.send(JSON.stringify({
            message: 'some_error'
        }), 409);
    });
};
```